# Neo4j Cypher query (ActiveGraph)

Tags: ruby, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I have the following Cypher query which I can run in a browser console to produce the desired result:

```
MATCH (start:`Neo4j::Record` {record_id: 1547}), (end:`Neo4j::Record` {record_id: 1850})
MATCH p=shortestPath((start)-[:`NEO4J::RECORD_ASSOCIATION`*]->(end))
RETURN p
```

In this case, there's a direct link between the records:

```
{
  "start": {
"identity": 62,
    /// lots of stuff cut here.
  ],
  "length": 1.0
}
```

...so the `"length": 1.0` is what I need.

I'd expect to be able to run this directly in the following manner:

```
result = ActiveGraph::Base.query(length_query)
```

But this returns an object of class Neo4j::Driver::Internal::InternalResult which is rather verbose and appears to not contain the data I need. There's reference to "p" being available in the form of `@keys=[:p],` but no sign that I can see otherwise.

Any hints on how to proceed would be welcome.

EDIT: There's definitely no sign of the "length" value when I run this. In the browser it only appears if I choose to view results as a table.

Comment: Why don't you return the length in the Cypher statement?

Comment: Is that not what the `RETURN p` statement is doing? If not, how would you write the query?

Comment: `RETURN length(p)`

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a result of `@records=[#<Neo4j::Driver::Internal::InternalRecord:0x00007f860c625f90 @keys=[:"length(p)"], @values=[1], @wrap=true>]`, so `result.to_a.first.values.first` (!) provides what's needed

Answer (score 0):

This is also dealt with by the answer to my other question, if I re-structure the data: [Constructing Activenode models for quicker querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75534619/constructing-activenode-models-for-quicker-querying)