# Constructing Activenode models for quicker querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Starting with a PostgresSQL database I'm making a copy of some of the data in Neo4j with the goal of making it easy to trace relation graphs between the records. The original setup involves a Record model and a RecordAssociation model, allowing labels to be applied to each RecordAssociation.

i.e. Record1 -> RecordAssociation -> Record2.

With the Neo4j representation I'd like to be able to start on any node and find all linked records out to a particular depth, then iterate over them and create a JSON structure of nodes and edges which can be used to plot a graph (I'm using Sigma.js). The code is something like this very simplified version:

```
depth = 3
result = {
  nodes: []
  edges: []
}
record = Neo4j::Record.where(record_id: id).first
record.linked_records(rel_length: {max: depth}).each_with_rel do |node, rel|
  result[:nodes] << {name: node.name}
  rel.each do |r|
    result[:edges] << {source: r.from_node, target: r.to_node}
  end
end
```

Here's a Neo4j::Record definition:

```
class Neo4j::Record
  include ActiveGraph::Node

  property :name
  property :record_id

  has_many :out, :linked_records, rel_class: 'Neo4j::RecordAssociation'.to_sym
end
```

This means that, going back to the original example, if I attempt to make a graph of Record1's relations then I will find Record2. But, the opposite is not true unless I create two relations in Neo4j, like this:

Record1 -> RecordAssociation -> Record2.

Record2 -> RecordAssociation -> Record1.

For whatever reason these queries are very slow. It may simply be that as I have ~ 4k records with perhaps 0-50 RecordAssociations on each it is going to be slow whatever I do.

Could there be any better way to structure the Neo4j Ruby models? As it happens I don't need to label the RecordAssociations and so could make do only with Neo4j::Record - if there was a way to query its associations to build up the array of nodes and edges. The documentation at https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Node.html is not entirely clear on this (at least not to me) so any associations would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. It's still a bit slow but it is at least usable.

Firstly, I changed the database setup to only having records going in one direction. Then, I enabled APOC in Neo4j (https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/). This allows code like the following to be used:

```
query = "MATCH (r:`Neo4j::Record` {record_id: #{id}}) CALL apoc.path.expand(r, null, null, 0, 3) YIELD path RETURN path, length(path) AS hops ORDER BY hops;"

all_links_result = ActiveGraph::Base.query(query).to_a
all_links_result.each do |res|
  # Create JSON with nodes and edges here.
end
```

Each result (`res` above) contains the start node, array of all links to the end node, the end node, and the number of hops.